# How to add two values in mysql with invoice number is same and show as 1 entry in table?

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a pos in php. I am saving the sale product by product if two items are purchased at the same time both are saved with the same invoice number as a row in MySQL. my problem is how can I add the selling price of both entries with the same invoice number and show in the table as one entry.
an invoice number is a random number auto generated.

```
productID sellingPrice invoiceNumber
   2          100          100
   1          20           100
```

AS

```
sellingPrice invoiceNumber
    120           100
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far

Comment: POS = Point of Sale system.

Comment: You can do `select sum(sellingPrice), invoiceNumber from table group by invoiceNumber`

Comment: yes Point of sale

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT sum(sellingPrice) as sellingPrice, invoiceNumber FROM tableName WHERE invoiceNumber = '100' group by invoiceNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Group By:

`select sum(sellingPrice) as sellingPrice, invoiceNumber from tableName group by invoiceNumber`

Comment: it will sum all the selling price field I only want to sum same invoice number field not the whole field

Comment: $query = "SELECT * FROM sales WHERE (saleDate BETWEEN '$var' AND '$var1')";
        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query);

Comment: I want to sum the same invoice number field and show all others as it is hoped you understand

Comment: @SohailFarooq This is pretty understandable that for that you need to add a where clause and pass the condition.